# Excel formula error: Too few arguments for INDIRECT() function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Upon entering this formula in a blank cell, I am getting "you've entered too few arguments for this function" error message.

```
 RSQ(INDIRECT("data!"&CHAR(64+ROW())&"1:"&CHAR(64+ROW())&"30"&",data!$"&CHAR(64+ROW())&"1:$"&CHAR(64+ROW())&"30"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RSQ` requires 2 ranges as parameters. each INDIRECT produces 1 range, so 2 are needed to supply the parameters to the function.

There is an extra wrapper that needs to be done to the `ROW()` function, because of the way it behaves (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124173/row-function-behaves-differently-inside-sum-and-sumproduct) for further details).

> =RSQ(INDIRECT("data!"&CHAR(SUM(ROW())+64)&"1:"&CHAR(SUM(ROW())+64)&"30"),INDIRECT("data!$"&CHAR(SUM(ROW())+64)&"1:$"&CHAR(SUM(ROW())+64)&"30"))

Also, I would take another look at your equation, because it's going to compare the same data.
e.g. in row 1, it compares `A1:A30` against `$A1:$A30` which results in the value `1`
   in row 2, it will compare `B1:B30` against `$B1:$B30` which also results in the value `1`

Comment: Success! Like in most cases with Excel and as expected, it was a simple fix. I'm aware the only value it'll produce is 1 - that's the way I want it. Part of a bigger plan.

Comment: Nice answer Sean, I missed the ROW() problem

Comment: @Micky Walia, not sure if it needs to be as convoluted, this formula should give the same answer and can also be copied down to increment the columns - `=RSQ(INDEX(data!A$1:Z$30,0,ROW()),INDEX(data!$A$1:$Z$30,0,ROW()))`

Comment: @barryhoudini You're right. Although, I modified my formula quite a bit to copy it down to increment the columns.    `RSQ(INDIRECT("data!$"&CHAR(SUM(COLUMN()+64))&"1:$"&CHAR(SUM(COLUMN()+64))&"30"),INDIRECT("data!"&CHAR(SUM(ROW()+64))&"1:"&CHAR(SUM(ROW()+64))&"30"))`

Answer (score 0):

The error is with RSQ function, you need two INDIRECT functions, I suspect, one for known_ys and one for known_xs

`=RSQ(INDIRECT("data!"&CHAR(64+ROW())&"1:"&CHAR(64+ROW())&"30"),INDIRECT("data!$"&CHAR(64+ROW())&"1:$"&CHAR(64+ROW())&"30"))`

Comment: This does not resolve the issue completely. It returns the `#NUM!` error - _There is a problem with a number used in the formula._